# How to compare an object containing a string?

Tags: java, arrays, object, compare

I have an array that contains the following strings

```
Object[] array = {"Tom","Jim","George"};
```

How can I compare each object as a String?

*** *Array must be type of Object and contain only String type of objects for my problem.Using String[] is pretty much obvious enough.***

Comment: So you want to compare an element of the array with another string?

Comment: Yeah exactly. And get an integer as result, like "compareTo" method.

Comment: If you are sure the oject is a string, you can cast it.

Comment: I get a ClassCastException :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like that:

```
String testString = "xyz";
int result = testString.compareTo((String)array[i]);
```

or for example:

```
int result = ((String)array[j]).compareTo((String)array[i]);
```

If you are not really sure if the array element is a `String`, use the `instanceof` operator to check.

Comment: Good point..But I dont have any String (like testString) to get the compareTo method. I only have objects in the array.

Comment: @Kanellis: See my edit. Maybe you missed the parentheses around the first casted element and therefore got the ClassCastException.

Comment: Yeah! Thats it! Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int result=-1;
    Object parameter="Tom";
    for(Object o: array){
    if(o.toString().equals(parameter.toString())){
     result=1;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah. Thats a good point. But how can I get the result of compare as an integer..just like compareTo method?

Comment: If I understand. I edit the answer. You wanna a int as result. 
Do you wanna just a some int as answer or you wanna the index?

Comment: Use the 'compareTo()' method to get a result just like the 'compareTo()' method.